# xUnit Test Runner failed to run tests through ReSharper

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, .net-core, xunit.net

- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3, all KB package updates are applied
- ReSharper 2016.1.2, latest
- According to my `project.json` file xunit references are;

  - `"xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "xunit.abstractions": "2.0.1-rc2",
    "xunit.assert": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "xunit.extensibility.core": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "xunit.extensibility.execution": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "xunit.runner.console": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.2.0-beta2-build1149",
    "xunit.runners": "2.0.0"`
- .Net framework is 4.5.2
- .Net Core Solution type which means .xproj

When i try to use ReSharper xUnit test runner, i'm encountering;

> "Unit Test Runner failed to run tests, Unable to run xUnit tests -
>   File not found:"D:\srcs\GitProjects..etc\bin\My.Tests.dll"
>   Parameter name: assemblyFileName

[image]
Sorry for Turkish exception details, i couldn't change yet.
Any idea about that? I searched a lot of forums and i couldn't find any useful stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. Haven't found a fix yet. If you check the path you'll see that `Debug` or `Release` is missing so the dll cannot be found.
Also when you say `package.json` I think you mean `project.json`. If that is the case, then you are working in a .net core solution. (as am I) probably best to mention that in your question.

Comment: @Rubanov, thanks for the comments, i edited the question. Yes xUnit runner need the path that should located under directly debug or release. I don't know, which tool is responsible for that, visual studio or xunit runner or resharper...

Comment: It's resharper. I am now using the Visual Studio Test Explorer. Make sure you have this in your project.json: `"testRunner": "xunit",` and `"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },`
After a build you should be able to test in Test Explorer

Comment: @Rubanov thanks for the tips. I applied what exactly that you said. And using now visual studio test explorer i can debug and run all tests. Resharper has to fix this.

Comment: You can download the Resharper EAP (early access program) of 2016.3 to start using it now. It is pre-release, but it's very stable. I've been using it with no problem so far. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.3+EAP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for **.NET Core** testing in **Resharper** is scheduled for 2016.3

The workaround is to use **Visual Studio Test Explorer**. (Test --> Windows --> Test Explorer)

The **project.json** file must contain `xunit` and `dotnet-test-xunit`:

```
{
  ...
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
  },
  ...
}
```

Rebuild your project and you should be able to successfully run your tests.
If you have Visual Studio 2015 you can start your test inside the code.

**Update**: (2017-02-08)
It also works with `nunit`;

```
{
  "testRunner": "nunit",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  "NUnit": "3.5.0",  
  "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-3"
  },
...
}
```

Comment: 2016.3 has been released, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper doesn't currently support .net core testing. This is scheduled for 2016.3.

Comment: Thanks for informing us.

Answer (score -1):

By installing the Early Access Program(2016.3) of Resharper, you will be able to run your dotnet core tests.
It supports both nunit and xunit. 
I installed it, and it solved the issue for me.

Link to the relase details:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/resharper-ultimate-2016-3-eap-build-1-details/